# Project Can't Build After Installing Neo4j Nuget

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j, nuget

I'm trying to build a project after installing the Neo4j.Driver Nuget and it crashes every time, and causing new errors:

```
api.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.Threading.ThreadPool 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature validity period has expired.
api.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.Net.NameResolution 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature validity period has expired.
api.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired.
api.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'runtime.native.System.Net.Security 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature validity period has expired.
api.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.Threading.Thread 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature validity period has expired.
api.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.ValueTuple 4.5.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired.
api.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.Net.Security 4.3.2' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature validity period has expired.
api.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.Security.Principal.Windows 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature validity period has expired.
api.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.ValueTuple 4.5.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature validity period has expired.
api.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature validity period has expired.
    14 Warning(s)
    10 Error(s)
```

I'm trying to build a project after installing the Neo4j.Driver Nuget and it crashes every time, and causing new errors:

After discarding the changes, the project builds successfully.
I tried to reinstall all packages, and it only happens with this package (I tried other versions).

Any ideas?

Comment: Please describe what kind of a project you are creating and show us some code so we can help you. From the above and the tags it looks like it is a .NET project.

Comment: @DavidAStumpf it's an ASP.NET Core. I've just added the package as I did with all of the rest.
What other details will help you understand the problem?

I'm following this guide: https://neo4j.com/developer/dotnet/

Comment: Where are you planning to run it: localhost, Azure, AWS? Seeing the code would be helpful. I've been running Neo4j from VB.NET code using NUGet packages and a Neo4jLib with a set of functions. I and others couuld help better if we saw what you are doing and the outcome you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it related to a bug on .net SDK version 5.0.201.

After updating to version 5.0.402, it solved the problem.